# Product Options are not coming for the configurable products in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute

Product options for the configurable products are not coming at the product page.

```
echo $this->getJsonConfig()
```

did not return any value and the page breaks after var spConfig = new Product.Config(. 
I cant see any error in the log files. When I am going to page source I can see 

 var spConfig = new Product.Config(
and page ends. It could not load rest of the things after that script. Only select boxes are showing but no options are there. 
[image]

I could not understand what is the issue. Please suggest some solutions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
// set error verbosity
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Than see the php error. and debug.

Comment: I have uncomment " ini_set('display_errors', 1);" and got the error.
The error is var spConfig = new Product.Config(<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getIsInStock() on a non-object in <b>public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php</b> on line <b>158</b><br />
Can some one suggest how to solve the issue.

Comment: Your magento version... 
in 1.9.2.4 , i have not any code like that..